# How to simulate api calls in VB.NET (Upload Data & File)

Tags: php, vb.net, api, post, api-key

I have an online reports viewer application that stores patients records as follows:

Web application view:
[image]

I have created a VB application that is meant to capture TextBoxes details from user:

VB application view:
[image]

VB application is supposed to capture & simulate api call to allow api to post the data into the website.

PHP code to simulate api calls:

```
<?php 

$post['api_id']="xxxx";
$post['api_key']="xxxx";

// Set customer data
$post['customer_system_id']="11221";
$post['customer_name']="New Customer 1";
$post['customer_email']="email@email.com";

// Set report data
$post['case_id']="123458";
$post['patient_cpr']="965847365";
$post['patient_name']="John Doe";
$post['patient_mrn']="5556632";

// Create report object
$post['report_file']= curl_file_create(realpath('small-logo.png'));

// Assign POST data
$ch = curl_init("url");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r(json_decode($response,true));

?>
```

** API ID/KEY + curl_init url are omitted for confidentiality.

I coded the following HTTPWebRequest but it gave me the below response:

```
{"Status":0,"error":"MISSING_FIELDS"}
```

Would very much appreciate if someone could guide me through simulating API calls in VB to and to correct me if I'm posting the data incorrectly.

VB Code I've done:

```
Dim postdata As String = "api_id=xxxxx&api_key=xxxxx&customer_system_id=999&customer_name=MHD&customer_email=admin@expressmedlabs.com&case_id=T22-999999&" _
    & "patient_cpr=999888777&patient_name=Mohamed A.Ameer&patient_mrn=996655&report_file=C:\ReportsPDF\xxxxx.pdf"

Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
Dim encod As New UTF8Encoding
Dim ByteData As Byte() = encod.GetBytes(postdata)

Dim Req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("API URL"), HttpWebRequest)
Req.Method = "POST"
Req.KeepAlive = True
Req.CookieContainer = tempCookies
Req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"
Req.ContentLength = postdata.Length

Dim stream As Stream = Req.GetRequestStream()
stream.Write(ByteData, 0, ByteData.Length)
stream.Close()

Dim response As HttpWebResponse
response = DirectCast(Req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
tempCookies.Add(response.Cookies)

Dim ReqReader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim responsemsg As String = ReqReader.ReadToEnd()
MsgBox("MSG: " & responsemsg, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Upload Response")
```

Comment: Well an API call is just a HTTP request, so you're basically on the right lines. What specific problem are you having? Stackoverflow is far better suited to solving specific problems or errors, we don't provide generic tutorials. See also [ask].

Comment: Or are you saying that the PHP script is meant to _receive_ the request from the C# application? Because your PHP code seems to be set up to _send_ a request. The way your question is worded makes it ambiguous, I can't quite work out whether it's a C# -> PHP request, or the other way around.

Comment: Ok. Why doesn't C# just post data direct to the web application? Why does PHP need to be an intermediary?

Comment: Well you're going to need the same credentials whether you send the data from a PHP application or a C# application, there's not really any difference. In the PHP you've got fields for API ID and API Key...presumably those are all you need to authenticate? If so, then C# can use them instead and make a HTTP request direct to the application.

Comment: I do have the api id/key, but don't know the code of applying a sample http request and using api id/key to post the data. Can you show me an example?

Comment: In PHP or C#? Besides, I'd need to know how the API expects you to send those within the request, which presumably is covered in its documentation. Should they be in a specific header, perhaps?

Comment: In C#, from my understanding I only need to post the data in C# to the PHP file. And then the PHP file must do the rest. That's all what I got from the company who developed the web app.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason you can't do it direct from C# as far as I can see. There are lots of libraries you can use in C# to make HTTP requests, which all have documentation and examples. RestSharp is a good one, quite easy to use.

Comment: From the cURL code shown, if that's an example provided by the supplier it seems that the API key and ID are simply added as parameters in the request body....unconventional, but I guess it must work. Another thought - instead of a separate C# program, why not have a simple HTML form to capture this data, then all you have to do is post the form to the PHP file? That'll reduce the work quite a bit compared to writing a C# app and making it generate a HTTP request to the PHP. Let the browser do the heavy lifting instead...

Comment: I'll check RestSharp. I cannot use HTML as I have a complete c# application that is already running offline inside the whole company. Will check if could get it done and get back. Thanks!

Comment: @ADyson Hello, I'm very sorry for incorrectly phrasing my question since the beginning. Now the PHP file was provided to show how API call is done. I need to simulate API call in VB.NET application and post the data to API and API will take care of posting the data. I've edited the code and added VB code to show where I reached.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So basically you're trying to re-write the PHP code in VB.NET, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: One obvious difference I can see is in the VB.NET version your `report_file` parameter is just a string containing the filename. Whereas in PHP the curl_file_create() function is used to actually get the _content_ of the file and put it into the POST data.

Comment: Hello @ADyson, yes I'm sure the code is incorrect. Unfortunately I don't know how to add each field in the request including API id & key for authentication. I'm really new to this and couldn't find exact answer to my question.

Comment: The other fields look OK, it's only the file which looks like a problem to me